# Asking user to input certain information

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this code that takes a csv files, filters from by a column and then plots the values of another column.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Desktop/Plot/dataframe.csv', delimiter=";", encoding='unicode_escape')
df['num_1'] = df['num_2'].str.split(',').str[0]
df['num_1'] = df['num_2'].astype('int64', copy=False)

X=df[df['Describe']=='The Start of Journey']['num_2'].values

dev_x= X 


# Set figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

plt.hist(dev_x, bins=5)


plt.title('Data')
```

This is the dataset

```
+-----+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
|     | name  |       Describe        | num_1  | num_2  |
+-----+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
|  0  | er    | The Start of Journey  |    17  |  249,5 |
|  1  | NaN   | NaN                   |    58  |   51,0 |
|  2  | NaN   | NaN                   |    14  |   66,5 |
|  3  | NaN   | NaN                   |   526  |   84,0 |
|  4  | be    | The end of journey    |     3  |   13,0 |
|  5  | tg    | Levels                |   342  |   34,0 |
|  6  | NaN   | NaN                   |   231  |   55,6 |
|  7  | NaN   | NaN                   |    23  |   75,0 |
|  8  | tf    | counts                |    54  |   34,6 |
|  9  | sf    | The Start of Journey  |    52  | 4324,0 |
| 10  | gd    | The Start of Journey  |   352  |   54.0 |
+-----+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
```

I want to modify the code so it does the following

1. Props to user to add the csv file
2. Prop the user to add the name of the column we want to filter ( this case `Describe` column)
3. Prop the user to add the string ( this case `The Start of Journey`)
4. Prop the user to add the name of the column we want to plot the data ( this case `num_2`)

I have checked other sources but due to the structure of the code I am having trouble regarding this.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python user input", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Also voting to close, reading in input is literally one line of code which you'll find from the first result of google, the rest is working with the pandas API. go play around, if you get stuck on a specific thing come back and someone will surely help.

Comment: What is your question? Are you just asking people to write code to fulfill your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `input()` function. You can have a variable like `x`, and do `x = input("Enter the CSV path>>> ")` (or something similar), and `x` will be a string with whatever the user input. Then you can use x later. For example, instead of 'Describe' you could just put `x`.

```
x = input("Enter the csv path>>>") # returns answer in string form
```